# What is the mathematical symbol/representation for the remainder operation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, terminology

Is there an equivalent in mathematical language to the modulo (or `mod`) function in computing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen the percent sign (%) represent *mod* in computing. So when you are thinking of as `x % n`, a mathematician would equivalently write this as $x \bmod n$.

There is a subtlety here, though. When you are using `mod` in computing, you are thinking of it as a function that returns the *least non-negative value that is the remainder after performing the division of $x$ by $n$.* Typically in mathematics, though, we think of *modulo* as a restriction on the set of numbers we are currently working with. You will hear the phrase "*we are working $\bmod n$ right now,*" and we'll have the modulo $\pmod n$ written off the side in parenthesis almost like a reminder.

You'll usually often see the notation $y \equiv x \pmod n$ and sometimes more you'll see the more compact notation $y \equiv_n x$. These both would be read as "$x$ and $y$ are *congruent* $\bmod n$". We choose to say that $x$ and $y$ are *congruent* (rather than *equivalent*) because they are just members of the same equivalence class $\bmod n$.

For a concrete example we can look at the integers modulo $7$, more concisely written as $\mathbb{Z}_7$. Now $\mathbb{Z}_7$ consists of $7$ elements, $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. But these elements aren't exactly numbers. Each of these elements in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ represents an *equivalence class*. The element $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ represents the *equivalence class* of all integers that are congruent to $3\pmod 7$, so it is the integers in the set $\{\dotsc, -11,-4,3,10,17, \dotsc\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical symbol in many computer languages and also mathematics is mod it represents modular divsion . Eg $15 mod 2=7$