# Math notation for modulo

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic

I have a little trouble understanding how to write a mathematically notation for `r = x%n`. How should I write this in math notation if I want to get the remainder value, after dividing by $n$? $r$ is also not just an integer in this case, just the rest of $x$ (double) divided by $n$ (integer), "$r = \operatorname{mod}(5.4, 3) = 2.4$" in this case. I think $x \equiv r \mod n$ means something different.

**Edit:** After thinking a while, I am still confused by the notation. Why is the notation $x \equiv r \mod n$ used at all? If $\operatorname{mod}$ is a mathematical operator like $\sin$ or $\cos$, why is the notation $r = \operatorname{mod}(x,n)$ not used always?

Comment: That's generally correct, $x\equiv r\mod n$ is usually assumed to be using integers, however it should be noted that the definitions do not limit the operation to only integers.

Comment: Consider the proof at https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/LucasLehmer.html for an example.

Comment: @abiessu While in this context I think so too, there is no difficulty in making sense of $x\equiv y\mod2\pi$ for $x,y\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: Consider $r=x-n\lfloor\frac xn\rfloor$

Comment: $$x\equiv r\mod n$$ almost always means $\ n\mid x-r\ $ , where $n$ is an integer greater than $\ 1\ $ and $\ x,r\ $ integers. This does not mean that $\ r\ $ is the minimum value in the residue class.

Comment: More explicitly, you can just write $r\in x+n\mathbf Z$ (although this does not imply that $0\leq r<n$). You can just write $r=x\mod n$. This is not standard when $r,x,n$ are not integers, but if you explain the convention when you use it, I don't think anyone is going to complain.

Comment: I am just confused by the notation of $x \equiv r \mod n$, since I want to write it like a general equation, like $r = ...$. Also if the notation is generally applied to intergers, is it ok to use it for real valued variables?

Comment: @Lemonbonbon: It is, as soon as you explain what you mean by that.

Comment: In particular, I think that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1559911/468350) is quite nice.  It pains me to say this, as I don't want to give Mike credit for doing anything right (before you jump on me, his office was down the hall from me, and I find it amusing to give him a bit of good natured ribbing from time to time), but his answer is spot-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write $``x \bmod n"$.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

> Given two positive numbers, a and n, a modulo n (abbreviated as a mod n) is the remainder of the Euclidean division of a by n, where a is the dividend and n is
> the divisor.

Note that it was not required that $a$ or $n$ be integers.